# Session Manager- Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Session Manager Plugin to store data.

I want Onboarding Screen only for the first time when user install the app

But when I tried to reinstalling the app or after clear data, Onboarding Screen is not shown.

My Code-

```
Future<Widget> determineScreen() async {
    try {
      bool seen = await SessionManager().get("seen") ?? false;
      bool isLoggedIn = await SessionManager().get("isLogin") ?? false;

      if (seen) {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          return LoginScreen();
        }
      } else {
        await SessionManager().set("seen", true);
        return Onboarding();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error determining screen: $e");
      //return LoginScreen();
      return NoInternet();
    }
  }
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
      var screen = await determineScreen();
      await Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen
            ),
      );
      setState(() {}); 
    });
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/SplashScreen2.png',),
              fit: BoxFit.cover
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```